# How to Custom Format Print .dat file column with awk

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed, duplicates

I've got this file

```
#id|firstName|lastName|gender|birthday|creationDate|locationIP|browserUsed
933|Mahinda|Perera|male|1989-12-03|2010-03-17T13:32:10.447+0000|192.248.2.123|Firefox
1129|Carmen|Lepland|female|1984-02-18|2010-02-28T04:39:58.781+0000|81.25.252.111|Internet Explorer
4194|Hồ Chí|Do|male|1988-10-14|2010-03-17T22:46:17.657+0000|103.10.89.118|Internet Explorer
8333|Chen|Wang|female|1980-02-02|2010-03-15T10:21:43.365+0000|1.4.16.148|Internet Explorer
```

And i want to find dublicate browsers with count...So i need something like this

```
Firefox 1
Internet Explorer 3
```

I am using this code but the result is not what i want

Code:

```
awk -F '|' '!/^($|[:space:]*#)/{ print $8}' $3 | sort  | uniq -c | awk '{print $2 , $1}'
```

Result:

```
Firefox 1
Internet 3
```

What can i do so i can have whole "Internet Explorer" and the count right of the words ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F'|' 'NR>1{c[$NF]++} END{for(k in c) print k, c[k]}' file
```

Explanation:

`NR>1` skip the header

`c[$NF]++` count distinct last fields in array c

`END{..` at the end iterate the keys in array c and print key and
counts

Comment: Works fine , thank you very much but can you explain me how this command works ?